# Proving V is a vector R-space [unusual operations]

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose the following operations are defined in the set $V = \{(a, b) \in \Bbb R^2:\, a,b > 0\}$:

addition: $(a, b) \oplus (c, d) = (ac, bd)$, $\forall (a, b),(c, d) \in  V$.

product by a scalar: $\alpha \times (a, b) = (a^\alpha, b^\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha\in \Bbb R$   $\forall (a, b) \in V$.

These are unusual operations. How to solve cases where the operations are given like that? ill be glad if someone who knows about it could explain.

Comment: Check the eight axioms in the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) of a vector space, but first, why $\oplus$ and $\times$ are well-defined operations on $V$? As a weird fact observe that $(1,1)$ plays the role of the zero vector in this case.

Comment: Mmmm there's a problem with the definition of $V$: It allows $a$ and $b$ to be both negative, so $a^{\alpha}$ and $b^{\alpha}$ do not make sense in $\mathbb{R}$. Are you sure that's the correct definition? If we require $a$ and $b$ to be positive, there should be no problem. Perhaps you meant to write $a, b > 0$ instead of $a.b > 0$.

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.   It clogs up the site.  Edit your original question to make it better.

Comment: I'm voting reopen *only because* this question has an accepted answer, as opposed to the proposed duplicate. The other one should be deleted and OP should be warned about spamming identical threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check that the axioms of a vector space are satisfied. I'll show you how to check the first four and leave the rest to you. I'll also assume that you meant
$$ V = \{ (a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid a, b > 0 \}. $$

Let $(a, b), (c, d), (e, f) $ be arbitrary elements of $V$.
First, as Azif pointed out in the comments, you need to show that $\oplus$ and $\times$ are well-defined operations on $V$: given that $(a, b), (c, d) \in V$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, can we deduce that $(a, b) \oplus (c, d) \in V$ and $\alpha (a, b) \in V$?

Consider $\oplus$. By the definition of $V$, we see that $a, b, c, d$ are all positive, so $ac$ and $bd$ are positive and we can conclude that $(a, b) \oplus (c, d) = (ac, bd) \in V$.

1. Addition is associative.
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{split}
   ( (a, b) \oplus (c, d) ) \oplus (e, f) & = (ac, bd) \oplus (e, f) \\ &= (ace, bdf) \\ &= (a, b) \oplus (ce, df) \\ &= (a, b) \oplus ( (c, d) \oplus (e, f) ).
   \end{split}
   \end{equation*}
2. There exists an additive identity. Consider $(1, 1) \in V$. We see that
   $$ (a, b) \oplus (1, 1) = (1, 1) \oplus (a, b) = (a, b). $$
3. Additive inverses exist. Since $(a, b) \in V$, both $a$ and $b$ are positive, so $\frac{1}{a}$ and $\frac{1}{b}$ exist and are positive as well, so $\left( \frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b} \right) \in V$. Moreover,

$$ (a, b) \oplus \left( \frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b} \right) =  \left( \frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b} \right) \oplus (a, b) = (1, 1) . $$

4. Addition is commutative.
   $$ (a, b) \oplus (c, d) = (ac, bd) = (ca, db) = (c, d) \oplus (a, b). $$

The operations $\oplus$ and $\times$ may seem unusual, but as you can see, the previous results depend on the usual properties of the real numbers.

Comment: What was the reason to answer a question which was *already nominated to be a duplicate* of another one? (You could better give this answer to *that another question*.)

Comment: You're right. I need to be more cautious in the future. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Omg, i just check it was a real typo in my material. I found the original book where this questions was from and it was a comma. Thanks! Now it makes real sense